# i have some marker, every marker with it's info. window , how can i customize them in one info window on javascript

Tags: javascript, json, maps, foursquare

### i have some marker, every marker with it's info. window , how can i  customize them in one info window, and every time it re-assign data when click on a different one? on javascript

```
self.getContent = '<div class="window-content" style="background-color:#a0785c;padding:5px;color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase; border-radius:5px;"><div class="title"><h4 style="color:#38c3ea;">' + self.title + "</h4></div>" + '<div class="extrContent"> ( ' + self.lat + ' , ' + self.lng + " ) </div>" + '<div class="extrContent"> city ->' + " " + self.city + "</div>" + '<div class="extrContent"> Street ->' + " " + self.street + "</div>" + '<div class="extrContent">' + self.checkinsCount + " checkins </div></div>";
    });
    self.getContent = '<div class="window-content" style="background-color:#a0785c;padding:5px;color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase; border-radius:5px;"><div class="title"><h4>' + self.title + "</h4></div>" + '<div class="extrContent">' + self.city + "</div>" + '<div class="extrContent">' + self.street + "</div>" + '<div class="extrContent">' + self.checkinsCount + "</div></div>";
    // define infoWindow 
    self.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: self.getContent
    });
    // add and show markers
    self.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.location.lat, data.location.lng),
        map: map,
        title: data.title,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    });
    // function to show markers on map
    this.isVisible = ko.observable(false);
    this.isVisible.subscribe(function(currentState) {
        if (currentState) {
            self.marker.setMap(map);
        } else {
            self.marker.setMap(null);
        }
    });
    this.isVisible(true);
    // Get contect infowindows
    self.marker.addListener('click', function() {
        // declare info window
        self.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: self.getContent
        });
        self.infoWindow.setContent(self.getContent);
        self.infoWindow.open(map, this);
        // set marker animation 
        self.marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: i have a problem that info window still opens even i click other one, i wanna it to be closed when i click another one, i think it may be resolved when i have only one info window and when i click new marker, a new data re-assign to it and the old closed automatically, but i have a problem with how to do it

Comment: I see, you want there to be only one infowindow. Here is an example that has a single `InfoWindow` object. Share this object between all the markers. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: still have the same problem, all markers are opened

Comment: what you need is a function that takes marker infoWindo and marker as parameters and call it at click event listener inside a loop that iterate over each marker.